# Reading text file in Lua using Luacom and ADODB: error

Tags: lua, ado, luacom

I am constructing a general purpose function to read a text file, which may be Ascii, UTF-8 or UTF-16.  (The encoding is known when the function is invoked). The file name may contain UTF8 characters, so the standard lua io functions are not a solution. I have no control over the Lua implementation (5.3) or the binary modules available in the environment.

My current code is:

```
require "luacom"
local function readTextFile(sPath, bUnicode, iBits)
    local fso = luacom.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if not fso:FileExists(sPath) then return false, "" end --check the file exists

    local so = luacom.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    --so.CharSet defaults to Unicode aka utf-16
    --so.Type defaults to text
      so.Mode = 1 --adModeRead

    if not bUnicode then
      so.CharSet = "ascii"
    elseif iBits == 8 then
      so.CharSet = "utf-8"
    end

    so:Open()
    so:LoadFromFile(sPath)
    local contents = so:ReadText()
    so:Close()
    return true, contents
end

--test Unicode(utf-16) files

local file = "D:\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\utf16.txt" --this exists
local booOK, factsetcontents = readTextFile(file, true, 16)
```

When executed I get the error:  `COM exception:(d:\my\lua\luacom-master\src\library\tluacom.cpp,382):Operation is not allowed in this context` on line 19 [local stream = so:LoadFromFile(sPath)]

I've pored over the ADO documentation and am obviously missing something that is staring me in the face!  Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

**ETA**: If I comment out the line so.Mode = 1, this works.  Which is great, but I don't understand why, which meaans I may end up making the same mistake unwittingly, whatever that mistake is!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about AdoDB Stream.Mode and why the function failed. But I think it's rather tricky to use a ADODB COM object on Windows to read ASCII/UTF8/UNICODE encoded files.

You can instead :

- use standard Lua io.open function in binary mode and use manual decoding of the bytes content
- use a binary module to do all the work
- use a specific Lua implementation for Windows that can read/write those kind of encoded files natively, like [LuaRT](https://www.luart.org)

Comment: Thanks, I've added some info to the Q to explain why the standard  lua io functions aren't suitable (file names may contain utf8 characters). I have no choice about the Lua implementation, or the binary modules available (which is why I'm writing a pure Lua module to do the job).

Comment: Ok, so your question is not Lua related : The mode property means the access mode of the ADODB Stream object. The value 1 means to open the Stream in read mode. See https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rec_mode.asp

Comment: As I said, I have read the documentation. I don't understand why setting the mode to read prevents me from reading the file. There is some conflict obviously but what is it?